# using ajax variable in php

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select style="width: 300px" id='Jproduk' name='selectJP' onchange="cekInput()">
        <option  value="" selected></option>
        <option  value="1">game</option>
        <option  value="2">itunes</option>
        <option  value="3">google</option>   </select>   

<script>

function cekInput(){
     $jprod= document.getElementById('Jproduk').value;
     alert($jprod);
}
</script>
```

Is `$jprod` an ajax code?

```
foreach($dataDp as $row) {
    if($row["operator"]==$jprod) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['kodepaket'] . '">'
            . $row['kodepaket'] . " - " . $row['namapaket']
            . '</option>';  }}
```

Why I cant do `$row["operator"] == $jprod` ??

thanks in advance

Comment: ajax is not a language, the var `$jprod` is into the javascript code which is executed on the client side so you cannot use it into the php code which is executed on the server side

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send this variable (data holds) to PHP, AJAX is good idea to do that:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select style="width: 300px" id='Jproduk' name='selectJP' onchange="cekInput()">
        <option  value="" selected></option>
        <option  value="1">game</option>
        <option  value="2">itunes</option>
        <option  value="3">google</option>   </select>

<script>

function cekInput(){
     jprod= document.getElementById('Jproduk').value;
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'test.php',
         data: "jprod=" + jprod,
         success: function(data)
         {
            alert("success!");
         }
     });
}
</script>
```

Now you can use this variable in your **test.php** file:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['jprod']) {
    var_dump($_POST['jprod']); exit;
}
```

> Also is very good idea to use newest version of jquery, version 1 is
>   out of date.

Comment: This is his code, and his jquery version :) i just add ajax method.

Comment: my bad, I did not see this line in the op post

Comment: Don't worry, i added this in my answer :)